# How to generate alert if first 4 digits in a string are zero using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, message, alert

I have a form field that users can input a tag number that can only be 9 characters/digits long. The tag number can start with the following: FT followed by seven digits or characters, FM followed by seven characters/digits, or 000 plus 6 characters or digits. If the user inputs four zeros and then 5 digits/characters I need a JavaScript alert to tell them that the tag number cannot start with four zeros. I have tried regular expression by saying:

```
if (tagNumber ==(/^(0){4}[0-9a-zA-Z]$/)
```

That does not work because if the user inputs a tag number with 1,2 or,3 zeros then it sends the alert. I have also tried using jQuery slice() to pick at each number starting from the left but that does not work either. Anything else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native `.slice()`

```
if("000056789".slice(0,4) === "0000"){
  alert("Cannot start with four zeroes");
}
```

Basically you can just do `.slice(0,4)` on your input string and validate if it is `0000`

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having. I was close to this I was just not adding the (0,4) in after the slice. Thanks to all who shared answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex

`/^0{4,}[1-9a-zA-Z]*$/mg`

This matches **invalid** input

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dH3gQ0

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways.

**REGEX**

```
 var re  = /^0{4}.*$/;
 // Incase if you want match only alpha numeric character, then 
 // var re  = /^0{4}[\w\d]*$/;

 re.test('0000434434')
```

**indexOf**

```
 var str = '0000434'
 // Check for indexOf '0000' is 0
 str.indexOf('0000') === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For strings .indexOf returns the position of the string you input. It will return -1 if not found, but will return 0 if the string is found at the start position, so this should work.

```
if ( tagNumber.indexOf( '0000' ) === 0 )
{
//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = "00004537".match(/^0{4}/);
if(result && result.length>0) {
   alert("number cannot start with four zeros");
}
```

if "result" not null(i.e. non empty array with the match), "0000" is found in the beginning of the string. else not found.